# Как отследить нажатие delete/стрелочки/shift

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытался через jQuery, но при нажатии вышеперечисленных клавиш выдаёт всегда 50 код клавиши и многие переменные, которые должны давать название клавиши не установлены (`undefined`). Через стандартный document.body.onkeydown всё тоже самое.

Проверял с одной и той же клавиатурой.

Comment: http://keycode.info/

Comment: Уже знаю об этом сайт, на нём тоже самое

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hr3s8wj3/6/)

```js
document.onkeydown = function(e)
{
  switch(e.keyCode)
  {
    case 38:
    alert('up');
    break;
    case 40:
    alert('down');
    break;
    case 37:
    alert('left');
    break;
    case 39:
    alert('right');
    break;
    case 46:
    alert('delete');
    break;
  }
  if (e.shiftKey)
  {
    alert('shift');
  }
}
```

Comment: Я же сказал, что "при нажатии вышеперечисленных клавиш выдаёт всегда 50й код клавиши", а 50 не подходит ни к одному из условий.

Comment: И ещё. `shift/ctrl/altKey` всегда `undefined`

Comment: @Дмитрий тогда покажите на примере как воспроизводится, иначе помогут только шаманы с бубнами, на моем фиддле работает или тоже всегда 50 код?

Comment: Да. Через Google Chrome 63.0.3239.132 всё ок, а на другом устройстве с Google Chrome 3.2171.1902 вот такая дичь.

Comment: @Дмитрий скорее это проблема именно старого браузера, посмотрю попозже, если что дополню ответ.